# PHP: forcing use of extended class in different namespace by core class / function

Tags: php, mongodb, namespaces

Background (although my problem can be generalised): I would like to integrate the [Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.core.php) core classes with [PhpRbac](http://phprbac.net/) (role based authentication) to add an additional layer of security to limit access to specific databases and collections. e.g. if the code attempts to access the collection "dbname.foo.bar.baz" it will check for existence of the PhpRbac permission "/mongo/dbname/foo/bar/baz" and ensure that the current user has permission.

I would like to force the core [`MongoClient::selectDB()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.selectdb.php) function to return my extended version of `MongoDB` rather than the core `MongoDB` as it usually does.

e.g.

(1) Define the extended version of `MongoDB`

```
namespace MyUniqueNamespace;

class MongoDB extends \MongoDB {

  public function __construct(){
    die("We're definitely using the extended version!");
  }

  public function someStandardFunction(){
    authoriseOrThrowException();
    return parent::someStandardFunction();
  }

}
```

(2) Force the core `MongoClient` (without modifying it) to use `\MyUniqueNameSpace\MongoDB` instead of `MongoDB`. Using `use` or `use ... as MongoDB` does not do the trick :(

```
use \MyUniqueNameSpace\MongoDB;
$cl = new MongoClient();
$db = $cl->selectDB("dbname"); //would die if it was using the extended function
```

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this? PHP can't cast as a different class and I don't want to start rewriting the Mongo classes because this is a general problem that I'll face when integrating PhpRbac with other functionality.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Looks like you'd need to extend `MongoClient`. Otherwise, I can't see a way around this at all.

Comment: Thanks @Phil - well [here's my solution should anyone wish to use or extend it](https://packagist.org/packages/oonix/mongo-rbac)

Answer (score 0):

You should add following use statement in your MongoClient class instead of where you're calling it:

```
use \MyUniqueNameSpace\MongoDB;
```